# Best Java deobfuscation tools as of date - [ques Closed]

Tags: java, obfuscation, deobfuscation

we have obfuscated our java source code and currently working on it, so make our source fool proof what are all thing to be done while obfuscation ?, how it can be prevented from de-obfuscation? and

What are all the de-obfuscation open source tool available right now?

Comment: Just so you know, there is no foolproof way to prevent decompilation of bytecode.  You can obfuscate it quite a bit, but the inherent structure in class files (as well as the requirement that most names be dynamically resolvable) prevents a lot of the tricks that are possible in languages that are closer to the metal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a deobfuscation tool.  What you are actually talking about is a decompiler.

A good obfuscator will remove most of the clues that a decompiler needs to produce readable source code.  However, it will not prevent someone with enough skill and determination from reverse engineering your code anyway.  In fact, there is NOTHING you can do to prevent that.

If you want to make a judgement on how easy / hard it would be, then the best answer is to attempt to do the reverse engineering yourself ... using **all** of the decompilers you can get your hands on.  (I imagine that you are really worried about someone attacking a critical part ... like the license key checking.  So focus on reverse engineering / circumventing that.)

Comment: thanks for ur comment, we are usig "dasho" obfuscator right now, as u said it matters on how hard we are obfuscating will give more complex in it.. So in which area obfuscation should be hard enough ?

Comment: @jerith - "So in which area obfuscation should be hard enough".  It is not clear what you are asking.  (And I did not say anything like that ...)  But the answer is probably that it is up to you / your manager to make that call.

Comment: @jerith - the point I was making is that you 1) obfuscate, 2) attempt to reverse engineer, then 3) decide whether the EFFORT required to reverse engineer is a sufficient deterrent.  If the answer is NO, then either look for a better obfuscator (and repeat the test), don't ship your product to users you don't trust, or put up with the piracy (or whatever) that you are trying to prevent.

Answer (score 1):

For Java I have used this obfuscation tool in the past with success: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/#

As a bonus it also shrinks the code.

I've never tried obfuscating my c/c++ code. This is the one of the obfuscators I know for c/c++ though I have never used it: http://freecode.com/projects/cxx-obfus

Comment: any tool deobfuscate the same to get the original source code.

Comment: @jerith There is no such tool. It would it beat the point of obfuscation! Obfuscation is irreversible.

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon: Nothing's completely irreversible, especially when it comes to obfuscating Java code.  The best you can hope for is to make it hard enough that most people decide it's not worth the effort.  You can give functions gobbledygook names, but someone can just change the names to something more sensible once they figure out what the functions do.  Which is not too difficult when all the Java API functions, and most stuff that uses reflection, can't be renamed.

Comment: What I meant is there is no tool that can do that for you (figuring out what the jibberish in the names mean..) You could do it manually, yes. @jerith asked for a `any tool deobfuscate the same to get the original source code`.

Answer (score 1):

We use [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) in our company.

Comment: Ok boss, any deobfuscation tool ?

Comment: You usually have to maintain a single file with special extension along with your source code. You need to update that file (specify which ones should not be obfuscated - for example methods that may be called using reflection) when doing patch builds or full builds. Of course the exceptions that arise won't show you the exact filenames and line numbers so you gotta use that file to figure out the actual errors.